# Build failure due to forking build

Tags: maven

I have a parent maven project with various modules.
I cleared my maven local repository.

Now, when I try to build the whole project, while building one of the modules, its pom is forking build for other modules and is creating jar with .lastUpdated extension.
Due to this my maven build is failing because instead of finding abc.jar it is getting abc.jar.lastUpdated in maven local repository.

1. Why is maven forking build for other modules?
2. How can I get rid of this .lastUpdated extension?

Comment: It would be good if you could share the pom as well for that 'one of the modules'

Comment: build isnt failing because of 'lastUpdated extension', its just that its not able to get the project dependencies. If abc.jar is a dependency then it should be either downloaded or locally installed in maven repository. else if its a dependent project, it should get install. (while doing mvn install). check your parent pom and repository location/url settings  in settings.xml

Comment: Changing the version of java doc plugin resolved the issue. May be java doc plugin was forking other processes which was resulting into build failure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you run javadoc plugin during a usual build?